# Is there any way to implement avaudiosession .duckothers without interrupting the UI. Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I activate ducking prior to playing the avaudioplayer using the following code.

```
do {

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient,  withOptions: .DuckOthers)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }

    do {

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

I use audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying to stop the ducking using:

```
do {

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)

    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

Ducking is activated and deactivated correctly, but the UI is stalled momentarily when activating ducking, which is a problem.

I've been trying to implement ducking asynchronously using dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0) but haven't had any success, even when forcing try. The UI still stalls despite trying use the async thread.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem. With Ducking, the UI interruption seems to be ~500ms for both `.setActive(true)` and `.setActive(false)`.
Best solution I found so far is to completely separate the changes in UI and the `.setActive()` using completions and notifications.

I tackled the problem this way:

- Do all changes in UI (All possible changes that still makes sense before the sound is heard)
- then on completion of those changes, do `.setActive(true)`
- then `.play()`
- then on completion of your audio, do `.setActive(false)`
- then resume UI changes

That seems to diminish the sensation of your application being "frozen" because your user is "receiving instructions" audibly and not visually as the documentation seems to imply.

> .DuckOthers
>
> Use this option if you want audio from your app (for example, voice prompts in a navigation app) to be heard over music or other currently playing audio. Note that ducking begins when you activate your app’s audio session and ends when you deactivate the session.
>
> If your app provides occasional spoken audio, such as in a turn-by-turn navigation app or an exercise app, you should also use the AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionInterruptSpokenAudioAndMixWithOthers option.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. My UI was blocked when the AVAudioSession was set to inactive. There is consistent 500ms pause when releasing the session.

I solved the problem by setting the AVAudioSession to deactivate on a separate thread. [Blog post about the problem here](https://thedon.me/2016/03/16/avaudiosession-and-ducking/).

Although my code is C# (using Xamarin), you can certainly do the same in Obj-C or Swift:

```
private void DeactivateAudioSession()
 {
  new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
  {
      var session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
      session.SetActive(false);
  })).Start();
}
```